# How to resolve ngx-toastr version issue in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular4-forms, angular-httpclient

I get the following error:

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module D:/AngularUI/AngularWebUI/node_modules/ngx-toastr/ngx-toastr.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

[image]

Comment: Either update angular to ^5 or downgrade ngx-toastr

Answer (score 4):

Try ngx-toastr@6.4.1-beta.0, I think this was the last available angular 4 version.

Use command:

```
npm install ngx-toastr@6.4.1-beta.0 --save
```